# Material turns into black and grey in box pattern

Tags: unreal-engine4

Characters which I downloaded have a right materials and designs, but when I open them they suddenly turn into black and grey in box pattern, in meshes and characters, and I don't know how to solve it.

Edit: solved. It takes a lot of time to compile shaders, and now it is compilled

Comment: Seems like it didn't compile the shaders properly. Did you try to replace materials with the downloaded ones?

Comment: It is solved. It takes a lot time to compile them, and when compiling ended they took a normal form, thanks